# Inventory Price Calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor, recursive-query

I'm in SQL 2005 and I'm trying to convert this Cursor into something that isn't a Cursor to determine if this is the most efficient way to do this.

```
        --Create cursor to determint total cost
DECLARE CostCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
        FOR SELECT  ReceiptQty
                   ,Price
            FROM    @temp_calculate
            ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC
OPEN CostCursor 
FETCH Next FROM CostCursor INTO @ReceiptQty,@Price
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
            IF @OnHandQty >= @ReceiptQty
               BEGIN
                           --SELECT @ReceiptQty,@Price, 1,@OnHandQty
                     SET @Cost = @ReceiptQty * @Price
                     SET @OnHandQty = @OnHandQty - @ReceiptQty
                     SET @TotalCost = @TotalCost + @Cost
               END
            ELSE
               BEGIN
                     IF @OnHandQty < @ReceiptQty
                        BEGIN
                              --SELECT @ReceiptQty,@Price, 2,@OnHandQty
                              SET @Cost = @OnHandQty * @Price
                              SET @OnHandQty = 0
                              SET @TotalCost = @TotalCost + @Cost
                              BREAK;
                        END
               END
            FETCH Next FROM CostCursor INTO @ReceiptQty,@Price
      END
CLOSE CostCursor
DEALLOCATE CostCursor
```

The system needs to go through and use the newest recieved inventory and price to determine what the paid for the on-hand is.

```
Ex. 1st Iteration: @OnHandQty = 8 RecievedQty = 5 Price = 1 UpdateDate = 1/20 Results:  @HandQty = 3 @TotalCost = $5
2nd Iteration: @OnHandQty = 3 RecievedQty = 6 Price = 2 UpdateDate = 1/10 Results:  @HandQty = 0 @TotalCost = $11
```

The Final Results tell me that the inventory I have on hand I paid $11 for.  If I was doing this in C# or any other Object Oriented langauge this screams Recursion to me.  I thought about a Recursive CTE could be more efficient.  I've only successfully done any Recursive CTE's for Heirarchy following types of Queries and I haven't been able to successfully wrap my head around a query that would achieve this another way.

Any help or a simple thats how it has to be would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, you should be able to do this recursively, although I think normally you'd use a window/OLAP function (`LAG()`, I think, although I don't think 2005 has it).  I'd worry about a stack-overflow type of exception, mostly.  Also, `SET @OnHandQty = 0` strikes me as 'wrong' - what happens if you physically have more than the computer is aware of?  You should allow the negative on-hand, at least temporarily.  And that nested `IF` should be unnecessary.  Although, I half think this could be done as normal... in any case, you shouldn't need a cursor.

Comment: I inherited this and can't talk to the original developer, long gone, The negative case is actually handled a bit later if we have more OnHand then we recieved its take to account in another place.  If we have more recieved then OnHand it just means we already shipped that product out.  A little Confusing.  It actually didn't originally have the break in there so the OnHand = 0 was stopping it from adding more to the total cost.  I just feel there should be a better way.

Comment: Are you sure that a recursive solution should improve performance?

Comment: No, I'm not really sure, but as I rule I always try to do complex things in SQL at least 2 ways.

Comment: I've abandonned doing this recursively.  While I think with more time we can get this working.  The time invested to the pay off is just not there in this case.  I'm actually convinced that it wouldn't be fast enough to justify the added complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_RawData_ProductID_UpdateDate ON #RawData (ProductID ASC , UpdateDate DESC , RowNumber ASC)

    DECLARE @TotalCost Decimal(30,5)
    DECLARE @OnHandQty Decimal(18,5)
    DECLARE @PreviousProductID Int

    UPDATE  #RawData
    SET     @TotalCost = TotalCost = CASE
                                          WHEN RowNumber > 1
                                          AND @OnHandQty >= ReceiptQuantity THEN @TotalCost + (ReceiptQuantity * Price)
                                          WHEN RowNumber > 1
                                          AND @OnHandQty < ReceiptQuantity THEN @TotalCost + (@OnHandQty * Price)
                                          WHEN RowNumber = 1
                                          AND OnHand >= ReceiptQuantity THEN (ReceiptQuantity * Price)
                                          WHEN RowNumber = 1
                                          AND OnHand < ReceiptQuantity THEN (OnHand * Price)
                                     END
           ,@OnHandQty = OnHandQty = CASE
                                          WHEN RowNumber > 1
                                          AND @OnHandQty >= ReceiptQuantity THEN @OnHandQty - ReceiptQuantity
                                          WHEN RowNumber > 1
                                          AND @OnHandQty < ReceiptQuantity THEN 0
                                          WHEN RowNumber = 1
                                          AND OnHand >= ReceiptQuantity THEN (OnHand - ReceiptQuantity)
                                          WHEN RowNumber = 1
                                          AND OnHand < ReceiptQuantity THEN 0
                                     END/*,
            @PreviousProductID = ProductID*/
    FROM    #RawData WITH (TABLOCKX)
    OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Welp, this was the solution I ended up coming up with.  I like to think the fine folks watching the #sqlhelp hashtag for pointing me to this article by Jeff Moden:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/

I did end up having to use a Rownumber on the table because it wasn't getting the first set of cases correctly.  Using this construct I brought retrieiving the dataset down from 17 minutes, best I been able to do, to 12 Seconds on my vastly slower dev box.  I'm confident production will lower that even more.

I've tested the output and I get the exact same results as the old way except for when 2 items for the same product have different price and the update time is the exact same.  One way may pick a different order then the other.  It of 15,624 items that only happened once where the varience was >= a penny.

Thanks everyone who answered here.  I ultimately went a different way but I wouldn't have found it without you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive CTE solution.  A row number column has to be present to make it work.  So I derived a new temp table (@temp_calculate2) containing a row number column.  Ideally, the row number column would be present in @temp_calculate, but I don't know enough about your situation as to whether or not you can modify the structure of @temp_calculate.

It turns out there are four basic ways to calculate a running total in SQL Server 2005 and later: via a join, a subquery, a recursive CTE, and a cursor.  I ran across a [blog entry by Jerry Nixon](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2010/04/tsql-running-total-cte-wins.html) that demonstrates the first three.  The results are quite stunning.  A recursive CTE is almost unbelievably fast compared to the join and subquery solutions.

Unfortunately, he didn't include a cursor solution.  I created one and ran it on my computer using his example data.  The cursor solution is only a little slower than the recursive CTE - 413ms vs. 273ms.

I don't know how much memory a cursor solution uses compared to a recursive CTE.  I'm not good enough with SQL Profiler to get that data, but I'd be curious to see how the two approaches compare regarding memory usage.

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

DECLARE @temp_calculate TABLE
(
  ReceiptQty INT,
  Price FLOAT,
  UpdateDate DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO @temp_calculate (ReceiptQty, Price, UpdateDate) VALUES (5, 1.0, '2012-1-20');
INSERT INTO @temp_calculate (ReceiptQty, Price, UpdateDate) VALUES (6, 2.0, '2012-1-10');
INSERT INTO @temp_calculate (ReceiptQty, Price, UpdateDate) VALUES (4, 3.0, '2012-1-08');

DECLARE @temp_calculate2 TABLE
(
  RowNumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ReceiptQty INT,
  Price FLOAT
);
INSERT INTO @temp_calculate2
  SELECT
      RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC),
      ReceiptQty,
      Price
    FROM
      @temp_calculate;

;WITH LineItemCosts (RowNumber, ReceiptQty, Price, RemainingQty, LineItemCost)
AS
(
  SELECT
      RowNumber,
      ReceiptQty,
      Price,
      8, -- OnHandQty
      ReceiptQty * Price
    FROM
      @temp_calculate2
    WHERE
      RowNumber = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
      T2.RowNumber,
      T2.ReceiptQty,
      T2.Price,
      LIC.RemainingQty - LIC.ReceiptQty,
      (LIC.RemainingQty - LIC.ReceiptQty) * T2.Price
    FROM
      LineItemCosts AS LIC
      INNER JOIN @temp_calculate2 AS T2 ON LIC.RowNumber + 1 = T2.RowNumber
)
/* Swap these SELECT statements to get a view of
   all of the data generated by the CTE. */
--SELECT * FROM LineItemCosts;
SELECT
    TotalCost = SUM(LineItemCost)
  FROM
    LineItemCosts
  WHERE
    LineItemCost > 0
  OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

Comment: I didn't think about introduding an ID for the Recursion.

Comment: I did get this modified to get the totals.  Unfortunately I couldn't get it for keeping the OnHandQty in the time I have for tweaking this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one thing you can try.  Admittedly, this isn't the type of thing I have to deal with real world, but I stay away from cursors.  I took your temp table `@temp_calculate` and added an `ID` ordered by `UPDATEDATE`. You could also add the fields you are wanting in your output to your temp table - @HandQty and @TotalCost as well as a new one called IndividulaCost - and run this one query and use it to `UPDATE` @HandQty and IndividulaCost .  Run one more `UPDATE` after, taking the same concept used here to get and update the total cost.  (In fact you may be able to use some of this on your insert to your temp table and eliminate a step.)

I don't think it is great, but I do believe it is better than a cursor.  Play with it and see what you think.

```
DECLARE @OnHandQty int
set @OnHandQty = 8
SELECT a.ID,
RECEIPTQty + TOTALOFFSET AS CURRENTOFFSET,
TOTALOFFSET,
CASE WHEN @OnHandQty - (RECEIPTQty + TOTALOFFSET) > 0 THEN RECEIPTQTY * PRICE
     ELSE (@OnHandQty  - TOTALOFFSET) * Price END AS CALCPRICE,
CASE WHEN @OnHandQty - RECEIPTQTY - TOTALOFFSET > 0 THEN @OnHandQty - RECEIPTQTY -   TOTALOFFSET
     ELSE 0 END AS HandQuantity
FROM SO_temp_calculate a
CROSS APPLY (   SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ReceiptQty), 0) AS TOTALOFFSET
                     FROM SO_temp_calculate B where a.id > b.id
                  ) X
```

RETURNS:

```
ID  CURRENTOFFSET   TOTALOFFSET CALCPRICE   HandQuantity
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          5           0           5           3
2         11           5           6           0
```

If you were using `SQL SERVER 2012` you could use `RANK` functions with `OVER` clause and `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.   Until you go there, this is one way to deal with Sliding Aggregations.

Comment: Looking at this I be worried it would run into the Triangular Join problem. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/